# iOS launchimages : sizes and names?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm creating an iOS app and I wanted to include the launch images. I created the ressource using XCode in Images.xcassets but the ressource contains 20 different formats. Moreover, XCode doesn't allow you to drag and drop if the filename doesn't correspond. I have two questions:

- Could someone list the 20 differents filenames and images sizes required?
- Why is there a difference between iPhone portrait 1x iOS **5,6** and iPhone portrait 1x iOS **7,8**? Have the sizes changed?

[image: 20 different formats]

Comment: I have found a ressource here: http://support.typeengine.net/knowledgebase/articles/174773-what-are-the-required-dimensions-and-file-names-fo but there are only 7 different formats

Comment: Launch image should be Default.png. The sizes are the screen sizes for each respective device in 1x, 2x (double original size).

Answer (score 0):

May be this should help you in achieving different launch images
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Answer (score 0):

The following links may help you-

http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

Comment: The first link is interesting but I still cannot figure the 20 different formats.